Are 4 shadow projections enough to fully identify a convex 3D shape?
So I was wondering, how many distinct shadows-projections (obtained from different lighting angles) would be enough to fully identify the shape of a 3D object ?
Cause, for example, 3 shadows aren't enough : consider a tetrahedron, which can give square shadows if illuminated from its edges.

So then, maybe 4 distinct shadows might be enough ? But that would constrain the shape to be convex, because if you take a cube with carved-out indentations, the resulting shadows would still look the same as a cube : 
So is there any definitive answer to this ? Is there a minimal number of shadow-projections that's enough to fully identify a convex 3D object ? Are there any conditions on the specific angles (I feel like if the lighting angles are different enough, more information will be conveyed).
I looked this up online, but couldn't find anything relating to this particular problem. I did, however, find this article, which mentions :

However, only four projections are necessary to estimate α2
with a mean error lower than 10%, whatever the studied 3-D
convex object is.

Just a small problem I've been thinking about. I'd love to get some more insight.
EDIT : to make the question slightly more precise, I suppose what I'm asking is actually a number of different questions :
1 - If I have an unknown convex 3D object in midair, and a flashlight, and I can only observe the projected shadow obtained from any angle I want, how many shadows do I need to be able to accuratelt identify the object (if possible) ?
2 - If I have an unknown convex 3D object in midair, and a flashlight, and I get a number $N$ of random, but unique shadow projections, is there a minimal number $N_{min}$ of shadows such that I can accurately identify the shape ? If not, are there any special conditions that I can add on the projection directions ?

Given any fixed set of $n$ directions, the unit  sphere and the Steinmetz solid obtained by intersecting $n$ cylinders of unit radius thru origin with axes along those directions have same set of projections (along those $n$ directions)

I believe my question was quite unclear. I see what you're getting at, but this involves fixing the projection directions to be identical to the axes of each cylinder. So that would mean that for any number $n$ of directions, one could construct an object that, even with $n$ distinct shadow projections, is still indiscernable from a sphere. Am I wrong ?

Yes, that's what I mean. So fixed number of fixed directions won't work. no matter how large that is.
